# Vaadin - Edit template in source mode does not effect

Tags: vaadin

I'm new to vaadin, i'm trying to edit downloaded templet from vaadin designer page. my question is when i am edit the css in sorce mode of the designer, they don't effect in the preview mode even run the application. i tried to change background color and font colors of header bar.

Actually i'm using a trial version, but vaadin online support saying there's no any restriction.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.root-layout.navigation-template-vaadin {
$root-background-color: #ffffff;
$template-font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;  

$header-bar-background: #009933;
$header-bar-font-size: 16px;
$header-bar-text-color: #0000;

$search-field-border: 0;
$search-field-bevel: 0;
$search-field-prompt-color: #fff;
$search-field-border-color: $header-bar-text-color;
$username-label-color: #fff;

$side-bar-background: #000;
$menu-button-selected-text-color: #1A1314;
$menu-button-selected-background: $root-background-color;
$menu-button-text-color: #fff;
$menu-button-icon-color: #5AAAFA;


background-color: $root-background-color;

.header-bar .v-nativebutton,
.side-bar .v-nativebutton {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    &:hover{
        cursor: pointer;
    }
}

.scroll-panel {
    background-color: $root-background-color;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;       
}

.header-bar {
    background-color: $header-bar-background;
    padding: 0px 15px 0 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 65px;

    > * {
        color: $header-bar-text-color;
        float: right;
        padding: 0;
        line-height: 20px;
        margin-left: 15px;
        font-size: $header-bar-font-size;
        font-family: $template-font-family;

        /** Vertically center everything **/ 
        position: relative;
        top: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }

    > .search-field {
        background: none;
        color: $search-field-prompt-color;
        padding-left: 5px;
        box-shadow: none;
        border: $search-field-border;
        border-bottom: solid 2px $search-field-border-color;
        border-radius: 0;
        font-style: italic;
    }

    .user-name-label {
        color: $username-label-color;
        text-align: right;
    }
}

.side-bar {
    background-color: $side-bar-background;
    width: 100px;

    > .menu-button {
        position: relative;
        color: $menu-button-text-color;
        height: 90px;

        &.selected{
            background-color: $menu-button-selected-background; 

            .v-nativebutton-caption {
                color: $menu-button-selected-text-color;
            }

        }

        .v-nativebutton-caption {
            font-family: $template-font-family;             
            font-size: .7em;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 8px;
            text-align: center;             
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }

        .v-icon {
            color: $menu-button-icon-color;
            position: absolute;
            font-size: 35px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            top: 10px;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
        }
    }
}   

.dashboard-layout {
    padding: 60px 60px 0 60px;
}

&[width-range~="321px-768px"] {
    .dashboard-layout{
        padding: 10px;
    }

    .dashboard-item {
        width: 100% !important;
        min-width: 321px;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .side-bar {
        width: 60px;

        > .menu-button{

            height: 50px;

            > .v-nativebutton-caption{
                visibility: hidden;
            }

            > .v-icon{
                top: 0;
            }
        }
    }

    .header-bar {
        height: 45px;
        padding: 2px;   
    }
}
}
.navigation-template-vaadin[width-range~="321px-768px"]{
visibility: visible;
}
</style>
   <meta charset="UTF-8" name="design-properties" content="            {&quot;RULERS_VISIBLE&quot;:true,&quot;GUIDELINES_VISIBLE&quot;:false,&quot;SNAP_TO_OBJECTS&quot;:true,&quot;SNAP_TO_GRID&quot;:true,&quot;SNAPPING_DISTANCE&quot;:10,&quot;JAVA_SOURCES_ROOT&quot;:&quot;src/main/java&quot;,&quot;THEME&quot;: &quot;mytheme&quot;}">
   </head> 
   <body> 
   <vaadin-vertical-layout style-name="root-layout navigation-template-vaadin"       responsive size-full _id="root_layout"> 
   <vaadin-css-layout style-name="header-bar" width-full _id="header_bar"> 
    <vaadin-native-button icon="fonticon://FontAwesome/f078" style-name="user- menu" width="20px" height="20px" plain-text _id="user_menu"></vaadin-native-button> 
    <vaadin-label style-name="user-name-label" width="200px" plain-text _id="user_name_label">
      John Smith 
    </vaadin-label> 
   </vaadin-css-layout> 
   <vaadin-horizontal-layout style-name="main-area-layout" size-full _id="main_area" :expand> 
     <vaadin-css-layout style-name="side-bar" height-full _id="side_bar"> 
     <vaadin-native-button icon="fonticon://FontAwesome/f080" style-name="menu-button selected" width-full plain-text _id="menuButton1">
       Dashboard 
     </vaadin-native-button> 
     <vaadin-native-button icon="fonticon://FontAwesome/f0f6" style-name="menu-button" width-full plain-text _id="menuButton2">
       Order 
     </vaadin-native-button> 
     <vaadin-native-button icon="fonticon://FontAwesome/f05a" style-name="menu-button" width-full plain-text _id="menuButton3">
       About 
     </vaadin-native-button> 
    </vaadin-css-layout> 
    <vaadin-panel style-name="scroll-panel" size-full _id="scroll_panel" :expand></vaadin-panel> 
   </vaadin-horizontal-layout> 
  </vaadin-vertical-layout>  
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: since you mentioned, that it also does not work, when you run the application, this might not be directly related to vaadin-designer.  please add the code or better a minimal example, that shows the problem.

Comment: Looping in @cfrick as well: I don't use the designer as I don't have a license, but just a wild thought - does the declarative format allow for _inline_ CSS definitions outside the [theme](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/themes/themes-overview.html)? I suspect that it would use the theme and ignore definitions such as those in your sample, but at this point it's just a hunch. Looking at the [designer page](https://vaadin.com/designer) (scroll to the end) it would seem that way...